# Switch Page without content from root page React

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

[image]I wanna switch from root ("/") to /login but I wanna that the content from root Page not in /register is
there. I wanna an new Page without content from the root page!!
I tried everthing, rlly!! I have no clue anymore ;(

Maybe u are better than me :D

My Code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route path="/" component={Gui}/>
                <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: You need the `exact` prop

Comment: Try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-https-2joju?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using `react-router`.

Use [the `<Switch>` component](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Switch) to only render the first matching route.

```
return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route path="/" exact component={Gui} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```